# Paytm integration with ionic framework

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

i am using this plugin for paytm integration with ionic (https://github.com/samyam-a/PayTM-PhoneGap-Plugin)

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/samyam-a/PayTM-PhoneGap-Plugin.git --variable GENERATE_URL=<Checksum Generation URL> --variable VERIFY_URL=<Checksum Validation Url> --variable MERCHANT_ID=<MerchantID> --variable INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID=<IndustryType> --variable WEBSITE=<WAPWebsiteName>

//I am using this function to start transaction inside controller

window.plugins.paytm.startPayment(txn_id, customer_id, email, phone, amount, successCallback, failureCallback);

//Also i have defined successCallback and failureCallback

function successCallback(response)
{
    alert("response=="+JSON.stringify(response))
}  

function failureCallback(error)
{
    alert(error)  
}
```

As am not getting any response and not able to know that this plugin is working or not

Comment: Can you explain how to use this Paytm integration with ionic framework?. Particullatly install plugin.

Comment: Is this working now... ? can you please help me in integrating the same

Answer (score 2):

Your way of passing callbacks is incorrect, callback is a function passed as an argument of a function. So the solution of your problem will be -

```
window.plugins.paytm.startPayment(txn_id, customer_id, email, phone, amount, 
function(response) {
    //success callback
}, function(error) {
    //failure callback
});
```